# How can i place Feature Image under title field in wp-admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I am creating my custom Image slider,

in register_post_type() -> i use : supports = "title,thumbnail";

i use only two thing in supports,  "title,thumbnail"

But post-thumbnails default position is Under Publish tab.

Its look ugly, I want to show feature image Under title fields.
Where editor show, i want to show my feature image on that position.

Kindly tell me how this possible?

```
$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'textdomain' ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'slider' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title','thumbnail')
);

register_post_type( 'slider', $args );
```

**IN case of not possible:**

If this not possible then tell me please:
when first time we open any post_type page, wordpress show 2 columns,
left side show title,editor,comments
or right side showing publish/thumbnail/category, etc

Is there any option to show default one column?
so all thing show in one side..

Answer (score 3):

Super late to the party, but well...

If you want to show your featured image right under the Post title in your Admin area, use this piece of code in your functions.php :

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'my_cpt_move_meta_box');

function my_cpt_move_meta_box(){
   remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'post_type', 'side' );
   add_meta_box('postimagediv', __('custom name'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'post_type', 'normal', 'high');
}
```

Be sure to change `post_type` to you rcustom post type slug. Additionally, you can add a custom name for th eimage (instead of 'Featured Image')

Answer (score -1):

You can simply drag the featured image under the Title field

Comment: I want to do this by development, When user open admin panel, default feature image show under title field.

Comment: Are you doing this for a premium theme for custom theme or a plugin?

Comment: For custom theme... Just for Practice... :)
I have HTML format theme, converting into WP-theme...

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-move-featured-image-box-from-side-to-main-column This link might help you. However if it fails, you can just drag and drop the featured image box.

Then for every new post the featured image will appear under the title